# MongoDB Iteration

Tags: php, javascript, performance, mongodb

I'm trying to find the fastest way to iterate through the data in MongoDB. I have 60k documents in collection and I want to `remove` all `fields` in each document which value is `NULL`. (Transferred from MySQL). My test function just to remove one field is:

```
  db.collection.find({cc_type:null}).forEach(function(u) {
            db.collection.update(u, {$unset:{"cc_name":1} 
            //some other null-value fields to check
});
```

And it takes ~20 seconds to go through the data. What am I doing wrong? Also, I'm using MongoDB driver for PHP. Wouldn't be more efficient to iterate data in PHP instead of using MongoDB instruments? What are the best practices to iterate through the large amount of data and made some changes to it (different changes for each document depending on fields that exist)?

Comment: My conclusion is: Removing multiple fields with iteration causes mongodb to reconstruct indexes which causes serious performance problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be faster to do it in one `update` operation.  In the shell it would be:

```
db.collection.update({cc_type:null}, {$unset: {cc_name: 1}}, false, true)
```

The `true` parameter is the `multi` flag so that it affects all docs instead of just the first one.

Comment: won't work because there is unknown amount of fields in each document that contain null values. How do I know which fields to unset?

Comment: @castt The idea would be to repeat the command once per field you want to remove null values from.

Comment: What if I don't know which field to check for null value? What if I have one of 60k document that have a unique field that have a null value?

Comment: Then this wouldn't be the right approach. :)  It does assume a known schema.

Comment: I thought that is why I'm using MongoDB - I don't have know and rely on fixed amount of fields in each document. What if I have a department "Marketing" that contains field "Markup_bonus" and have 10k other departments that don't? May be async updates would be faster (in this case I can use external instruments)?